# Print all the 3 consecutive digits that can be equal to a given number

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

How can I write a recursive backtracking function `count(N,S)` in which it prints all `N`-digit numbers such that the sum of each 3 consecutive digits in the number is exactly equal to `S` where `N` will be less than or equal to 10, and is from 0 to 27.

Code:

```
def count(S):
    n = int(S)
    if n % 3 == 0:
        print(int(n / 3 - 1),int(n / 3),int(n / 3 + 1))
    else:
        print(None)
S = 27
count(S)
```

Sample Output:

```
8 9 10
```

I'm quite confused on how can I write this recursively.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? where you stuck ? what is your logic to solve this  ?

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: can you provide an expected output?

Comment: I have provided an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function is not recursive. To make it recursive, you'd basically have to call `count(n-1, s)` somewhere within the execution of `count(n, s)`. One way to do it would be like this:

- if `n > 1`, get possible solutions for `n-1` and append any digit that still satisfied the condition
- if `n == 0` just return `""` (it's a bit easier if the function returns strings, not actual integers)

As a generator function, this could look somewhat like this. Of course, you can just as well collect the results in a list and `return` them, or just get the count of such numbers and return that.

```
def count(n, s):
    if n > 0:
        for x in count(n-1, s):
            for d in range(10):
                y = str(d) + x
                if len(y) < 3 or sum(map(int, y[:3])) == s:
                    yield y
    else:
        yield ""

for x in count(5, 15):
    print(x)
```

Comment: It seems that I have misunderstood the problem. Sorry about that.